# ASP.NET MVC with JQuery $post and parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, parameters

What is wrong with this code. The code is finding the javascript and debug1 shown. If I remove the parameter p the code also founds mycontrol action and debug2 is shown.

View:

```
function method(p) {
    alert("debug1");
    $.post('../MyController/MyAction/' + p, function() {
        alert("debug2");
        $('#panel').empty().html('<img src="../Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" / >');
        $('#panel').load('../Controller/Index');
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult MyAction(int p)
    {
       // Some code

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Check the "net" tab in firebug and you will probably find the problem. Also, how is your routes set up?

Comment: Can you post the code that invokes 'method', and the relevant section from your Global.asax.cs file - I'd suspect that the value of p is not an integer and the URL can not , therefore, be routed correctly. Also, start using a HTTP sniffer, such as Fiddler (A lugin for IE) to find out exactly what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like you have a problem with your routes. You can't change the name of your parameter if you don't change your routes. A route that would work for your scenario is:

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute",
            "MyController/MyAction/{p}",
            new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction", p = "" }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change it like this:

```
$.post('../MyController/MyAction/p=' + p, function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

That function is a callback and will get called regardless of success or failure.  If you're calling a webservice, try including a success = true/false property as part of your result.  That way you can do the following

```
`$.post('../MyController/MyAction/' + p, function(result) {
    if (!result.success) return;

    alert("debug2");
    $('#panel').empty().html('<img src="../Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" / >');
    $('#panel').load('../Controller/Index');
});`
```

Comment: yeah that might be a good ide, but the problem is that the execution not steping into my action method. If I change the inparametername in MyAction to id instead of index that I actually use it works. Someopne who can explain?